# How to iterate through each rows in a dataframe and rename the value to index name if value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 100 columns and 160 rows. some columns have empty values in them. I want to iterate through each row in the dataframe and check if value exists in each column. If value exists, I want to rename the value to the row index name.
Sample of my data

```
index  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
row1   col1        col3        col5
row2         col2              col5
row3                                 col6
row4                                     
row5   col1              col4
```

desired output

```
index  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
row1   row1        row1        row1
row2         row2              row2
row3                                 row3
row4                                     
row5   row5              row5
```

I am trying to do it in pandas. I know for iterating rows, `df.iterrows()` can be used. But how to define this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[None, 'col1'], 'col2':['col2', None]}, index=['row1', 'row2'])
df = df.where(df.isnull(), df.index.to_series(), axis=0)
```

output:

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 |  | row1 |
| row2 | row2 |  |

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I thought I would have to write a loop, This is so much simple.